# Displace modifier using an Image Texture on a Grid Mesh

Tags: texturing, displacement

[image: displace modifier does not fill grid area]

I am trying to apply a displacement to a grid mesh for a Lithophane and a cookie cutter.

I create an image Texture, add a Grid mesh and apply a Displace modifier.  Unfortunately the displacement is only on a small portion of the center of the grid.  How can I get the displacement to fill the Grid?

Here is a link to the blender file. http://www.michael-sadler.com/uploads/displace_texture.blend

and here is the image. http://www.michael-sadler.com/uploads/greyscale-raider2.jpg

Answer (score 1):

In the modifier you should use *Texture Coordinates* > *UV* in order to control how the picture will print on the surface. So beforehand you must select your plane, go in *Edit* mode, select all and unwrap with <kbd>U</kbd> > *Unwrap*. I've also tested with a *Subdivision Surface* modifier above and below the *Displacement* modifier, it looks like it works better (note that your picture is very pixelated though so it will never be perfect).

[image]